# Track upvotes on discordbotlist.com/servers

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am creating bot in Discord.js and I would like to reward users for bumping/upvoting our server. I know there are bots that can track bumps on [disboard.org](https://disboard.org) (eg. bump reminder).

But what about [discordbotlist.com/servers](https://discordbotlist.com/servers)? If some user upvotes our server, is there any way how to find out the user identity? I checked their [API](https://docs.discordbotlist.com), but there is only event for upvoting bot, not server.

Comment: I'd ask them directly if you can? They have a discord server, and there's an email address in their page footer too.

Comment: `Our API is provided for users to get information on bots, submit their bot statistics and receive webhook requests when someone votes for their bot.` I searched there too and I haven't found a single thing concerning voting servers so I don't think you can but try asking on their discord server